# How can I define Propositional Expansion precisely?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

Suppose that our universe of discourse is $X=\{ x_1, x_2, \cdots , x_n \}$ 
Then, intuitively, the following seems to be truth.

$$(\exists x\in X) (P(x)) := (P(x_1) \lor P(x_2) \lor \cdots \lor P(x_n))$$

$$(\forall x\in X) (P(x)) := (P(x_1) \wedge P(x_2) \wedge \cdots \wedge P(x_n))$$

I want to make this definition clearer.
And from this definition, I want to prove the  properties about quantifiers only using the inference rules of propositional logic.  (I have heard about infinitary logic. What I want is just a case where the universe of discourse is finite.)

If you have an idea, or if you know the references, please help me.

Comment: It is quite hard... Propositional formulas have finite lenght, while fitst-order logic deals also with infinite domains.

Comment: See [Infinitary logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/).

Comment: I have heard about infinitary logic. What I want is just a case where the universe of discourse is finite.

Comment: Ok; if the universe $X$ is *finite*, then the above definitions are correct.

Comment: With the above def, [Universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) is simply [Conjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: What about existential instantiation??